# in C, how do I store a String type AND an int type in the same variable?

Tags: c, variables, types, storage

I want to store an integer and a String in a variable called X and then display it.

```
int X;
printf("enter a number or a name")
scanf("%d", &X);
printf("%d", X);
```

Obviously I would need to declare variable X with both String type and int type, how do I do that in C? thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Can you express the problem in terms of the behavior you're trying to achieve, without reference to what should be stored in which variable?

Comment: I want to a variable that can store integers or a string.

Comment: You have some problem you're trying to solve, and you think that "storing an integer and a string in the same variable" is the way to solve it.  You're almost certainly mistaken.  Tell us about the problem you're trying to solve, and we can help you figure out how to solve it.  What do you want your program to do?  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I prompt the user to enter a number or the word exit to exit the program.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that. True, you can store two types in the same variable -- look up what a `union` does -- but you can't give one of those to `scanf()` and scan for *either* a string *or* a number.

Declare `X` as a string, `scanf()` for a string, then use `strtol()` to try to read a number from the string. If `strtol()` returns zero *and* `errno` is set (this last is important, because `strtol()` will also return zero if the user types `0`), then the conversion failed and there was no number, so you got a name.

Answer (score 7):

In a comment, you've (finally) indicated what you're trying to accomplish:

> I prompt the user to enter a number or the word exit to exit the program.

You've assumed, *incorrectly*, that storing either a string or an integer into the same variable is the way do to this.  It isn't.

Here's a general outline:

1. Read a line of input into a string.  Use `fgets()` for this.
2. Check whether the line of input is the string `"exit"`.  Remember that `fgets()` leaves the newline (`'\n'`) character in the string; you'll have to allow for that.  To compare string values, use `strcmp()`.  If the input string matches `"exit"`, exit the program.
3. If the string wasn't `"exit"`, check whether it's an integer -- more precisely, whether it's a sequence of characters representing an integer.  You can use `strtol()` for this.  For example, if the input string is `"123"`, then `strtol()` will return the `long` value `123`.  `strtol()` can also tell you if the integer value represented by the string is out of range, or whether it represents an integer value at all.  Decide what you want to do if the input is `"foobar"`, or `"-123"`, or `""`.

You're going to want to carefully read the documentation for all these functions.

The key point is that you'll need *two* variables, an array of `char` to hold the input line, and an integer (`int` or `long`) to hold the converted integer value *if* the string holds the representation of an integer.

(I'm not providing code because, frankly, this smells like homework.)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct StringAndInt
{
    int theInt;
    char *theString; /* or whatever type you want */
};

struct StringAndInt X;
```

C++ has nicer options.

Comment: Its pretty obvious that this will not help him at all. He wants to scanf either a string or an integer at the same time, which is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is. He can `scanf` into the string part and then `atoi` it into the integer part if he wants. He can also add a flag to indicate which value he wants to use.

Comment: *"C++ has nicer options."* Not really. :-) You'll still end up declaring either a `struct` or a `class`, which are virtually identical functionally.

Comment: They're identical functionally, but much simpler to use. For example, you can use `pair<int,string>`. You get all the memory management for the string and you don't need to declare a class or struct.

Comment: Giving a rocket launcher to the rookie is considered harmful.

Comment: A `struct` is now considered a *rocket launcher*?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that. But you can read the input as a string and convert it to an int

```
char input[25];
int value = 0;

fgets(input, 25, stdin);
value = atoi(input);

printf("String Value = %s and Int Value = %d", input, value);
```